# Discord issue with role pinging

Tags: discord.js

**Hello**
I am trying to use code that will ping a role after it has sent a message. I've been told to try something like this, but it won't work.`message.channel.send('The roles within The Virgina Empire are as follows: \n \n <@&ID>'+727232200138817557+'>Engineer` 
however it will not ping the role but instead it will return true, I then tried to fix it further and got this: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4r9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try replacing
`<@&ID>'+727232200138817557`
with
`<@&727232200138817557>`? It should mention the role.

Comment: This works, if anyone comes across this, Make sure it is placed inside the "". Thank you Phoenix!